# AngularJS JSON GET from PHP File

Tags: angularjs

My first attempt at AngularJS and I'm stuck at my first get method.

Where in jQuery I'd use $.ajax() I've gotten the below and I get an error

```
var theApp = angular.module('theApp', []);
theApp.controller('ContentController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
theApp.controller('MenuSideController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/directory/assets/inc/category.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.list = data;
    });

}]);
```

The error I get

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specifying the string version of `$http` in your parameter list, so Angular isn't passing the service in.

Change this line:

```
theApp.controller('MenuSideController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http)
```

To this:

```
theApp.controller('MenuSideController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http)
```